# Drag and Drop controls and overlapping between

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I'm developing a small tool where you can drag and drop controls with the mouse, such as buttons, comboboxes, groupboxes, etc...

As the mouse moves, the control moves too, so the user can get a preview of the position of that control. The problem comes when, the control being dragged is going from one container to another one. Usually resulting in that control moving correctly but just under the second container, and therefore, not visible for the user. Let's say that we have GroupBox A and GroupBox B, and the user wants to move Button from A to B. When the action starts, the button is visible while the movement is inside the bounds of A, but when the mouse gets into B, the Buttons just appears to be in a lower layer of the interface and it becomes invisible.

I've tried to fix it with .BringToFront() and .SendToBack() without results. I'm having some flickering problems also trying to create a bitmap to create that preview even using the methods recomended here to solve it.

Is there a way of fixing it without having to use bitmaps that solves the layer problem?